# How can I place the player into a 360° video in UE4?

Tags: unreal, video, 360-video

I have a 360° video (6 separate videos stitched together into a panorama) with a first person view walking through an environment. I would like to put this in a game engine such that the actor can walk forward and backward and it will feel like they are in the environment.

I have tried this in UE4 but am somewhat new to all this. I'm not opposed to using UDK or Unity if that is easier. I have created a `MediaTexture` from the video asset. Now I'm trying to create a `Material` sphere that uses the `MediaTexture` and reflects it back so the actor is essentially in a spinning sphere. I keep getting stuck with these errors:

[image: screenshot]

I understand that I must next construct a blueprint that reads the actor's movement to play back the video, and also rotate the texture coordinates according to the view of actor.

How can I do this?

Comment: What you want to do is not done the way you intend to do it. A panoramic video is one path a person could walk. It doesn't translate to a 3d world directly.

Comment: Attempting to summarise: You'd like the player to be able to wind backward and forward in time in that 360°-video with their movement controls and use the mouse to look around?

Comment: Yes exactly. The goal is ultimately to add objects and build interaction on top of that otherwise I would just use a 360° video player

Comment: @baconwichsand Did you ever work this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an animated [skybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_%28video_games%29). You'd simulate player movement by scrubbing the animation depending on backward/forward input.

And a basic first person camera gives you the view rotation for free.

I don't if UE4 can do this, and how, but I'd start by checking these tutorials on YouTube and work out the blueprint from there:

- [Unreal Engine 4 Tutorial: Skybox Creation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjOhQ1DeQ8s) - for the basics
- [Unreal Engine 4 Tutorial - Time Of Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xt_TIYthRUE) - for some kind of animated skybox